# A somewhat complex problem of generic information loss

Tags: typescript

I have a class, that is, 'C'. I hope that its generic 'T' can be obtained from the instantiation parameters, and the generic 'G' can be converted from the generic 'T' (the 'TypeTo' part in the article is only for demonstration and is not meaningful).

```
type Type = 't1' | 't2'

type TypeTo<T extends Type> = T

class C<T extends Type = Type, G = TypeTo<T>> {
  g?: T

  constructor(readonly p: { t: T }) {
  }
}
```

Secondly, I have a function 'F', which uses the 'Record<string, C>' type as the parameter, and determines the return value type according to the parameter type (the 'F' part in the article is only for demonstration, and is not meaningful)

```
function F<T extends Record<string, C<any, any>>>(p: T) {
  return 0 as unknown as { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K]['g'], void> }
}
```

Next, type test

```
// A<"t1", "t1">
const a = new C({ t: 't1' } as const)

// {a1: "t1"}
const b = F({ a1: a })
```

Everything is normal here, but if I don't want to define an extra 'a' variable and use the following method, the generic information will be lost

```
// {a1: any}
const c = F({ a1: new C({ t: 't1' } as const) })
```

Many types of tools are used at the same time in the above, and this problem may not occur without one of them. I am designing a very novel model. For this reason, I have tried dozens of ways of writing. Other ways of writing may have some problems. I have been thinking about this problem for a week. The above way of writing is a simple reproduction of the most feasible solution I have tried so far

Comment: Your `C` class is not structurally dependent on `G`, which can cause inference failure [as described in the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--); TS's type system is *structural* and not *nominal*.  You should never have unused type parameters.  If you add a structural dependence as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJAg6m) it should help.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: [ts playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAJXRW) shows the type of `c` is `{a1: "t1"}`